# Create vector by linear combinations of two vectors at a time

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In James Gentle's Matrix Algebra book, the first exercise says that given $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ we can construct any vector in $\mathbb R^n$ by taking linear combinations of these vectors two at a time. After giving the problem some thought, I was unable to come up with an algorithm to say, construct $\begin{pmatrix}4\\5\\6\end{pmatrix}$ from $\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\\4\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\4\\5\end{pmatrix}$. I know how to set up the system of 3 equations but some kind of step by step procedure taking vectors two at a time and coming up with the  $(4,5,6)$ vector is new. So there are $_3C_2$ ways to choose 2 vectors, I am unsure if that's the way to go; or if we should linearly combine the first two, and then try to linearly combine the result of that with the third one. Any hints or ideas?

As an example of the kind of procedure (although for a completely different problem), if we had some vectors and wanted to select a maximal linearly independent subset, we could select any vector, then select a linearly independent vector to that (if there was one), and so on. So the answer to this problem should also be fairly procedural.

Comment: If your original set of vectors are linearly independent, it won't always be possible to write any vector in terms of only two vectors. For an example, consider the simple case of trying to construct $\langle1,1,1\rangle$ from only two vectors of the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @Stephen Donovan, I believe he is just saying that you take the linear combinations two at a time (computationally or algorithmically), but is aware that you need all $n$ vectors.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry I guess I didn't read that very carefully

Comment: It says "assume $n$ linearly independent vectors and then for any $(n+1)$st vector, showing that it is a linear combination of the others by building it up one by one from linear combinations of two of the linearly independent vectors."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the point (will delete if so), but if you have the coefficients $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ for the linear combination, then just form an array $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ of the basis vectors, and an algorithm is given by

\begin{align}
&\text{initialize $u_2=a_1v_1+a_2v_2$}\\
\\
&\text{for $k=3,\dots n$}\\
&u_k=u_{k-1}+a_kv_k\\
&\text{end}
\end{align}

Comment: I think this is what’s meant